# php/mysql - PHP function cannot detect mysql connection, when fixing the error becomes too many connection

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have `function.php`

```
function functionname() {
    include_once ("connection.php");    
    // Do Something
   return $variable
}
```

And a `connection.php` that goes as follows

```
<?php
    try{
        $db = new PDO ('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=project', 'root', '');
    }
    catch (PDOException $ex){
        echo "Error!:" . $ex -> getMessage() . " Cannot Connect"; 
    }

?>
```

I've been trying to run a php function but it's can't detect the MySql connection. If I try making `include_once`   into just `include` inside the `function.php` the error becomes too many connection.

The connection works except when use inside a function. I've been trying to run the `function.php` into a seperate `thirdPHPpage.php` through the following code

```
    include_once ("connection.php");
    include_once ("functions.php");


    $string = functionname();
    echo $string;
```

Comment: please post the code that is calling functionname()

Comment: Do you use try {} without catch {} block?

Comment: @MVG1984 I use a catch it in I'll edit my code again, sorry

Comment: @prifs you've lost 'n' in 'PDOExceptio' :)

Comment: @MVG1984  I've edited it, and it the same error still occurs, thanks anyway

Comment: [Accessing a PDO connection in your code](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples/connect_to_mysql#access). The rest of the article is also worth to read and implement in your connection code.